# EasyMock JUnit testing throws error on the setter method

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I am using easyMock for JUnit testing. I want to test a method which gets a Project object as its arguments and sets the modify date of that project and persists it in db.

So e.g.

```
public void setProject(Project project) {
 project.setModifyDate(new Date());
 this.reporsitory.persist(project);
 }
```

Now at my test method I have tow mocked projects. For one of them I have set the return value of the getModifyDate. For the other mocked project object I just call the setProject(mockedProject); Now I assertEqual these two project objects.

The problem is easymock throws me an error at the project.setModifyDate(new Date()) of the class which I am testing.

Exception : Unexpected method call project.setModifyDate(..).. Expected:1, Actual:0.

It seems that it does not expect the setter method. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is because of the type of mock object you created. It expects your code to call every method you defined when the one call executes. I cannot remember the exact name but i think it is something like nicemock, versus a strictmock whick makes your code execute every expected method. You should use EasyMock.createNiceMock() for your mock object. The error you have is because it expects you to call setModifyDate but your code didn't for that call.

Your call is unexpected because you must have not put EasyMock.expected for that method. You need to add your mock object .expected(getMethod).andReturns(something).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used createNiceMock() and that error went away. I am getting other errors which I am going to resolve.